# WebSocketSharp Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'

Tags: c#, node.js, websocket

I am wokring on a C# application that communicates with a node.js server via a secure websocket. There is also a javascript client that connects to the same websocket hosted on the node server. The javascript client connects successfully connects to the node server. However the c# application throws the error described in the title.

I used the SimpleWebSocketClient extension for chrome to connect to my socket. This works fine. 
I also tried websocket4net for the C# application. This doesn't work either.
I used the wss://echo.websocket.org websocket with my c# application and it works fine. However I have to set `_socket.SslConfiguration.EnabledSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.tls12;`

The Node Server

```
const app = require('express')()
const fs      = require("fs");        // file system core module
var https   = require("https").createServer({
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/certs/cert.pem"),
    key:  fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/certs/key.pem")
}, app)
const express = require("express");   // web framework external module

// Setup and configure Express http server. Expect a subfolder called "static" to be the web root.
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static/"));

const ws = require('ws')
const wss = new ws.Server({
    server: https
});

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
        ws.send('reply from server : ' + message)
    });

    ws.send('something');
});

// Listen on port 8080
https.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('listening on https://localhost:8080')
})
```

And here is the C# Code

```
_socket = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:8080");

            _id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            _socket.OnOpen += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("WebSocket Connection is now Open with ID: " + _id);


            };

            _socket.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("On Message");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            };

            _socket.Connect();
```

I'm confused why my C# application doesn't work. It should be able to build a connection just like with `wss://echo.websocket.org`